# Value and reference type in generic type implementation

Tags: c#, .net, oop, generics, types

I searched about `generic type in C#` and I made this conclusion:

1. All reference types are based on `Class`
2. All value types are based on `struct`
3. The main differences between struct and class, apart the global differences between value and reference type, are :

- No inheritance in struct
- The struct can not contain an empty constructor(without arguments)

4. There are six **basic** implementations of a generic type:

> - Where T: class ==>the generic parameter must be a reference type
> - Where T:classA ==>the generic parameter must be an instance of the
>   class **classA**
> - Where T:InterfaceA ==> the generic parameter must implement the interface **InterfaceA**
> - Where T:New() ==> the generic parameter must be a class + have a
>   default empty constructor
> - Where T:U ==> the generic parameter must be derived the class **U** or
>   implement the interface **U**
> - Where T: struct ==> the generic parameter must be a value type

So I need to know:

1. If my conclusion is correct?
2. I can't understand the difference between :

> - where T: New() ==> class with empty constructor
> - where T: class, New() ==> class with empty constructor

Why the second form is used? Why not just use the first one?

Comment: Enums are value types too, but you don't declare them as `struct`. Oh, and as of C# 6, structs can specify parameterless constructors.

Comment: [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) article provides a nice summary.

Comment: *Where T:Interface ==> the generic parameter must be an interface* doesn't exist. There are `struct` and `class`, but no `interface` (to be clear: `public class C<T> where T : interface { }` doesn't compile). Note that the case `T : U` is correct (`U` can be a class or an interface)

Comment: Note that if you look https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx, they had the cases a little different: the end concepts are the same, but for example U is the case of class `C<T, U> where T : U`, the classA is named `<base class name>`, and it is specified that the T can be the `<base class name>` or a derived type, the `Interface` is `<interface name>` (similar to `base class name` but with interfaces),

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're describing are generic *constraints*.

> Where T:New() ==> the generic parameter must be a class + have a default empty 
>   constructor

No, that just says "the type argument must have a parameterless constructor". That actually includes *all* value types. Even though you couldn't declare your own parameterless constructors for structs before C# 6, you could always *call* them. For example:

```
Guid guid = new Guid();
```

So if you have:

```
public void Foo<T>() where T : new()
```

it's perfectly valid to call

```
Foo<Guid>();
```

Answer (score 2):

The generic constraint `new()` means that the type has a parameterless constructor.  That type could be either a struct or a class.  structs cannot provide a *custom* parameterless constructor, that is because all structs have a parameterless constructor already provided for them, with a default behavior *that they cannot change*.  It doesn't mean that structs can never be created with a parameterless constructor.

Comment: In C# 6 you can specify custom parameterless constructors. They won't be called in all situations (e.g. creating arrays) but they will in simple cases.

Comment: @JonSkeet I know, but I intentionally avoid discussing features from products that haven't been officially related yet unless the question is specifically asking about that product.  For most people it's information that just isn't relevant, since they don't have access to the language.

Comment: Well VS2015 RC is now out - everyone can download it, and it's well documented. It just feels like emphasising information which we *know* will be out of date in a few months is counter-productive.

Answer (score 1):

> The struct can not contain an empty constructor(without arguments).

Not true. The struct will **always** have a parameterless constructor. You are not however allowed to change it from the default parameterless constructor that you get automatically.